# Spring MVC Thymeleaf Kotlin

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, kotlin, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass form to controller but object is empty (looks like gets values from default constructor instead of form). And dunno why `@Valid` doesn't work.

Code:

**Endpoint**

```
    @PostMapping("/add") 
fun addDevice(@Valid @ModelAttribute device: Device, model: ModelMap): ModelAndView {
    deviceRepository.save(device)
    return ModelAndView("redirect:/devices/all", model)
}
```

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
data class Device(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Int? = null,
        @NotNull
        val name: String? = "",
        @Min(10)
        @Max(30)
        val price: Int? = null,
        @Size(min = 8)
        val secretPhrase: String? = ""
) : Serializable
```

**Form**

```
<h1>Add Device</h1>
    <!--/*@thymesVar id="device" type="com.example.demo.Device"*/-->
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/devices/add}" th:object="${device}" th:method="post">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Name Cannot Be Null</label>
            <input type="text" minlength="1" th:field="*{name}"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Secret Phrase Min Length 8</label>
            <input type="password" minlength="8" th:field="*{secretPhrase}"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>Price Between 10-30</label>
            <input type="number" min="10" max="30" th:field="*{price}"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Add"></input>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you use `val` instead of `var` in your data class.

And  Spring MVC Thymeleaf calls the no args constructor of your entity class(data classes always have one).
And cannot set the fields because they are final.

Just replacing `val` with `var` solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks! It should definitely be noted somewhere in documentation.